# Jquery IE7 (:"Visible") validator don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, css

I have one problema this jquery works fine on IE8, 9 E 10 but IE7 don't work,

IE7 thinks all controls are visible=true, they problem is controlToValidate.is(":visible") always return true (but this only happens on IE7)

```
function ValidateRequiredField(source, args) {
    var validateTrue = parseFloat($("[id$=mylabel]").val()) <= 0;
    var _val = ConvertNumber.ToDecimal(args.Value);
    var language = $("[id$=ddlLanguage] option:selected").val();
    var validateChek = false;
    args.IsValid = true;

    var controlToValidate = $("#" + source.controltovalidate);

    if (controlToValidate.is(":visible") && _val < 0 && parseFloat($("[id$=hdnTotal22]").val()) > 0) {
        args.IsValid = false;
        if (language == "pt-BR")
            source.errormessage = "mensagem.";
        if (language == "en-US")
            source.errormessage = "required.";
        if (language == "es-ES")
            source.errormessage = "requier.";
        return;
    } else if(controlToValidate.is(":visible") && _val > 0 && validateTrue) {
        args.IsValid = false;
        if (language == "pt-BR")
            source.errormessage = "Obrigatório.";
        if (language == "en-US")
            source.errormessage = "required.";
        if (language == "es-ES")
            source.errormessage = "requier.";
    }
}
```

sorry for bad english

Comment: have a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7016033/jquery-count-visible-doesnt-work-in-ie7

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be an [issue in IE7](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4334) for old jQuery versions. You can upgrade your jQuery version or try this.

```
$(controlToValidate).css('display') == 'none'
```